# How to move the map by code in react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

[image]

Hi  i want to make a button that can move the map to the user current location, i read the [docs](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app) but i still don't understand which code to move the map like when we type and enter a location in autocomplete, or should i re-render the map with new lat long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you have to change the center of the map to the user location and re-render the map component. Like this:

```
<GoogleMap
    id="marker-example"
    mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
    zoom={2}
    center={center}
  >
    <Marker
      onLoad={onLoad}
      position={position}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: yes change the location (lat & long) and re render the component do change the map position, haha its so basic. idk why i forgot this. thanks.